# Why no output when index value is 0

Tags: c

Change the value of index from o to 1. loop is printing value. Why it is not printing any value when index is assigned to 0?

Currently i = 0 - No Output
Make i = 1 - infinite loop

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0;i++;i<100)
    {
        printf("Mahesh\n");
    }
}

enter code here
```

Comment: What is "enter code here"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**C** `for loop` structure:

```
for ( init; condition; increment )
```

You have actually added `i++` in the place of condition and `i<100` in the place of increment.

Flow Control of `for loop` in C:

- init step is executed first and only once.
- Condition is evaluated next and if it is True, the body of the loop is executed. If False, the body of the loop doesn't execute and the flow jumps to the next statement after the for loop.
- After the body of the loop executes once, the flow control jumps to increment statement and then condition is evaluated again.
- Body of loop, Condition and increment steps are repeated in the same order till the condition becomes False after which the for loop terminates.

Your loop is:

```
for(int i = 0;i++;i<100)
```

In this, you have `i++` as the condition. Now, in this `i` is evaluated first followed `++`. Since, `i is 0`, it leads to the loop exiting as the condition evaluates to `False`. But, if you change `i to 1`, the condition (i.e. i) evaluates to `True` and it enters the loop.

If you have not done this deliberately, you need the loop like below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for a for loop in C is as follows:

```
for ( init; condition; increment ) {
   statement(s);
}
```

-init: initialising the index variable with the value you would like to start the iteration at.

-condition: the condition for the iteration to continue until met

-incremenet: indicating how much you want the program to incremenet your index by

Hence in your example is should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    //yourcode
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: True but this does not say what is the problem with initializing with a zero value.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters of for loop are:

```
    for(initialization; Condition; Next iteration initialization){
    //code
    }
```

The initialization(s) can be more than one separated by commas.
The condition will continue if have 1 (or the value TRUE which means the same thing as 1) or will break if the condition is not met i.e the value 0 (or FALSE). You can have multiple conditions as well by the use of && or || or commas.
The third parameter is what you want to do in the next iteration. It can have multiple commands too. I suggest you run the following code and change it to observe the results:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
        int i,j;
        for( i=0,j=0;i<10 || j<5;i++,j++)
            printf("%d\t%d\n",i,j);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
                            // Postfix Increment Operator
    for (i = 0; i++; i<100) // Condition is false, Because the i is Zero
    {
        printf("Mahesh");
    }

    printf("%d", i);        // i outputs One here

                            // Prefix Increment Operator
    for (i = 0; ++i; i<100) // Condition is True, Because the i is One
    {
        printf("Mahesh");
    }
}
```